# Ember.js ArrayController usage

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How i can use ArrayController in Ember.js 1.0pre?

From documentation:

```
MyApp.listController = Ember.ArrayController.create();
```

raises this:

```
TypeError: a[c].create is not a function
```

If i replace `create` with `extend`, it rises:

```
TypeError: b.addArrayObserver is not a function
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle of your use case please ?

Comment: Came across exactly the same issue. What was the solution from your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure, that you've added jquery 1.7.x as well. Ember depends on it.